# How to minimize or resize the image on supertooltip at pictureedit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, devexpress

My problem is when I pointed the cursor in picture their is a `supertooltip` with image. But the image inside the `supertooltip` is too big. How to resize it programmatically.

```
Public com As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
Public da As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
Public dr As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
Public ds As DataSet

Dim confirm As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  con.Close()
  con.Open()
  confirm = "select PPhoto From user_tbl"
  dr = com.ExecuteReader

  While dr.Read
    BarEditItem10.EditValue = Image.FromFile(pathfrm.PathPhoto.Text & dr.GetString("PPhoto"))
    Dim resImage As Image = Image.FromFile(pathfrm.PathPhoto.Text & dr.GetString("PPhoto"))
    Dim sTooltip2 As SuperToolTip = New SuperToolTip
    ' Create an object to initialize the SuperToolTip.
    Dim args As SuperToolTipSetupArgs = New SuperToolTipSetupArgs
    args.Title.Text = "Profile Picture"
    args.Contents.Text = "This is a Profile Picture"
    args.Contents.Image = resImage
    sTooltip2.Setup(args)
    BarEditItem10.SuperTip = sTooltip2
  End While
  con.Close()
End sub
```

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcBO1.png)

When i pointed the cursor in picture (Second Image)

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9OWt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest re-sizing the image before assigning it to your SuperToolTip. I detail how to do this in a my [Previewing Images in a SuperToolTip](https://dx-developers.com/2015/03/21/previewing-images-in-a-supertooltip/) blog post.

Essentially I just use a static helper class to re-size the image:

```
static internal Image ScaleThumbnailImage(Image ImageToScale, int MaxWidth, int MaxHeight)
{
    double ratioX = (double)MaxWidth / ImageToScale.Width;
    double ratioY = (double)MaxHeight / ImageToScale.Height;
    double ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    int newWidth = (int)(ImageToScale.Width * ratio);
    int newHeight = (int)(ImageToScale.Height * ratio);

    Image newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(ImageToScale, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

    return newImage; 
}
```

This is done within the ToolTipController's GetActiveObjectInfo event handler:

```
private void toolTipController1_GetActiveObjectInfo(object sender, DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipControllerGetActiveObjectInfoEventArgs e)
{

Image MyImage = Image.FromFile("C:\\your_file_here.jpg");

ToolTipControlInfo toolTipInfo = null;
SuperToolTip toolTip = new SuperToolTip();

toolTipInfo = new ToolTipControlInfo(Guid.NewGuid(), "My Image");
ToolTipItem item1 = new ToolTipItem();

item1.Image = ScaleThumbnailImage(MyImage, 640, 480);

toolTip.Items.Add(item1);

toolTipInfo.SuperTip = toolTip;
e.Info = toolTipInfo;
}
```